# C# Deserialze XML to an Object

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization

I am trying to deserialize xml to an object using C#.

This is my XML.

```
<Products>
  <Product>
    <Name>Test</Name>
    <Price Amount="12.95">£ 12.95</Price>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

And this is my code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var filePath = @"C:\Eastpoint\TestApps\TestHunterSuppliers\bin\Debug\Sample.xml";
        var reader = new XmlTextReader(filePath);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Products));
        var products = (Products)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        Console.WriteLine(products.Product.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(products.Product.Price.Amount);
    }
}

public class Products
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Price Price { get; set; }
}

public class Price
{
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

By using the above code I am getting the product object but properties of the price object are always deserializing to null values.

Could somebody advice me what I am missing.

Thanks,
Naresh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default behavior of [.NET's XML serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx#Remarks) is to serialize properties to XML elements. The value of the property becomes the inner text of the XML element corresponding to the property. That is, if you serialized your objects it would look like this:

```
<Products>
  <Product>
    <Name>Test</Name>
    <Price>
      <Amount>12.95</Amount>
      <Value>£ 12.95</Value>
    </Price>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

In your case, you need to instruct the serializer to put `Price.Amount` into an attribute and to write `Price.Value` as `Price`'s inner text. The easiest way to do this is to decorate the properties requiring non-default serialization with appropriate [XmlXxx] attributes:

```
...
[XmlAttribute]
public string Amount { get ; set ; }

[XmlText]
public string Value { get ; set ; }
...
```

Incidentally, if your `Products` is supposed to contain more than one product, you will need to modify your code like this:

```
...
[XmlElement ("Product")]
public Product[] All { get ; set ; }
...
```

The attribute instructs the serializer not to create an `<All>` element to hold the individual products' elements. You can also use other collections like `List<Product>`, but you should create them beforehand like this:

```
...
[XmlElement ("Product")]
public readonly List<Product> All = new List<Product> () ;
...
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining getting into collection. Actually that was going to be my next question.

Comment: Yeah, I am clairvoyant sometimes ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your original test code working using `FileStream`,

Tested code sample:

```
            var filePath = @"C:\Eastpoint\TestApps\TestHunterSuppliers\bin\Debug\Sample.xml";
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Products));

            //Setting dummy object to create the xml
            Products myProducts = new Products { Product = new Product { Name = "Papers", Price = new Price { Amount = "10", Value = "20" } } };

            var strWrite = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            serializer.Serialize(strWrite, myProducts);
            strWrite.Close();


            //////////////////////////////

            var strRead = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
            var products = (Products)serializer.Deserialize(strRead);
            strRead.Close();

            Console.WriteLine(products.Product.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(products.Product.Price.Amount);
```

And to get the price as an attribute in the XML document:

```
        public class Price
        {
            [XmlAttribute]
            public string Amount { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }
```